# Change SIM PIN code on Nokia 2610

Tags: sim, pin

*Note: I'm asking this question here because it's the only StackExchange website I can find that deals with phones, and Nokia has some Windows phones.*

On a Nokia 2610 (which is not a Windows phone), how do I change the PIN code of my SIM card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dial `**04*oldpin*newpin*newpin#`.

For example, to change your PIN code from 5678 to 8765 dial `**04*5678*8765*8765#`.

I inferred this from the following two sources neither of which was very precise or correct:

- https://mobilespecs.net/phone/codes/Nokia/Nokia_2610.html
- https://www.hardreset.info/devices/nokia/nokia-2610/codes/